# How can i insert a generated Password

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a question. I would like to include a previously created password in a PostRequest. 
But I'm not sure how it works.

```
@PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser (@RequestBody User user)
    {
        String Password =generatePassword(10);

        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        InsertDefaultValue app=new InsertDefaultValue();
        app.insertDefaultTemplate("Sehr geehrter Kunde, Ihr Container wird morgen zugestellt", user.getUserName(), 1);
        app.insertDefaultTemplate("Sehr geehrter Kunde, Ihr Container wird heute gegen 10 Uhr zugestellt", user.getUserName(), 2);
        app.insertDefaultTemplate("Sehr geehrter Kunde, Ihr Container wird morgen abgeholt", user.getUserName(), 3);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                .path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId()).toUri();
                return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

This is my PostRequest.

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
     private static final String ALPHABET = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

     public static String generatePassword(int length) {
            StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                returnValue.append(ALPHABET.charAt(RANDOM.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
            }
            return new String(returnValue);
        }
```

This is my method to generate a password. It is also in my resource class.

```
package sendMessage.UserMicroservice;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name= "AuthenticateUser")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private boolean active;
    private String roles;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;

    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And this is my Entity class. 
As soon as I save a new user in my database using PostRequest, I want the generated password to be saved as well. Can someone give me a hint where I can find a suitable solution. I searched the internet for 2 hours now.

Comment: user.setPassword(password)?

Comment: ok thanks. Sorry for the stupid question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you also setting the generated password in your user class ?

i.e.

```
  user.setPassword(password)
```

before calling

```
 User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
```